# ¿Por qué no retorna los meses ordenados de forma ascendente en PostgreSQL 12.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql-12

Mi query devuelve de la tabla *sales* el monto total de las ventas de cada mes, pero no está retornando los meses de forma ordenada. Es decir, muestra primero el total del mes Febrero, después Enero y Marzo.

Esta es la query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sales.date, 'Month') AS "mes",
SUM(sales.total_price) AS "total"
FROM sales
where extract(year from sales.date) = '2021'
GROUP BY mes
ORDER BY mes
asc;
```

Acá el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: nota al margen... los meses estan ordenados... alfabeticamente... que no es lo mismo que numericamente....

Answer (score 2):

Tu error te da porque estás ordenando el mes como cadenas de caracteres, y tu lo que buscas es ordenarlo de acuerdo a su orden en el calendario.

Para ello debes sustituir tu **order by** y poner:

```
order by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sales.date)
```

De esta forma se ordenará por el número del mes y no por su nombre.

Comment: gracias por responder! sale este error:  la columna «sales.date» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación
order by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sales.date)..........entonces puse GROUP BY(sales_detail), pero lista el total de cada dia del mes

Comment: Prueba poner group by TO_CHAR(sales.date, 'Month')

Comment: Al agregar  group by TO_CHAR(sales.date, 'Month')..Vuelve a mostrar este error: ERROR:  la columna «sales.date» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación
LINE 6: ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sales.date)

Comment: Cuantos campos seleccionas?

Comment: En el ejemplo que pones no seleccionas sales.date, lo que seleccionas es el mes de la fecha y la suma de los precios

Comment: No, porque crei que con poner as "mes" lo entenderia. seria SELECT sales.date, TO_CHAR(sales.date, 'Month') AS "mes", ??

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120298/discussion-between-japv-and-claudio).

Answer (score 1):

La solucion fue hacer la consulta de esta manera:

```sql
select
case 
    when date_part('month', date) = 1 then 'Enero' 
    when date_part('month', date) = 2 then 'Febrero'
    when date_part('month', date) = 3 then 'Marzo'
    when date_part('month', date) = 4 then 'Abril'
    when date_part('month', date) = 5 then 'Mayo'
    when date_part('month', date) = 6 then 'Junio'
    when date_part('month', date) = 7 then 'Julio'
    when date_part('month', date) = 8 then 'Agosto'
    when date_part('month', date) = 9 then 'Septiembre'
    when date_part('month', date) = 10 then 'Octubre'
    when date_part('month', date) = 11 then 'Noviembre'
    Else 'Diciembre'
End  as Mes,
sum(total_price) as total_price 
from Sales 
where date_part('year', date) = 2021
group by date_part('month', date)
order by 1
```